# Swift 3 ,how reload a view if login fails

Tags: ios, swift

When I launch my app I have to use TouchID to login. It works correctly if I log, but If I click on "Cancel" button the app shows me a white view. I would like the app to totally close and go to the Home.
I tried it but when I click on the app logo again it appears as white page

```
UIControl().sendAction(#selector(URLSessionTask.suspend), to: UIApplication.shared, for: nil)
```

As alternative way I would like also that appear again the main page in which I have to use TouchId.
How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Post the parts of your code that you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

You can as a user to login with TouchID in `applicationWillEnterForeground` (each time when an app opens). In case if you use TouchID for secure app entering. You can not close an app programmatically. It's prohibited.